# NullPointerException error while trying to display TextView within MaterialCardView xml object

Tags: java, android

I am working through an Android Studio tutorial and get stuck at this line in my `BookRecViewAdaptor.java` file:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onVBindViewHolder: Called");
        holder.txtName.setText(books.get(position).getName());
        ...
```

Below is the error I am receiving on the 3rd line - btw I know that I am inside the code as in the Logcat, directly above the error I see "`onVBindViewHolder: Called`" (from line 2 above)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mylibrary, PID: 12001
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mylibrary.BookRecViewAdaptor.onBindViewHolder(BookRecViewAdaptor.java:42)
        at com.example.mylibrary.BookRecViewAdaptor.onBindViewHolder(BookRecViewAdaptor.java:21)
        ...
```

I have looked through many postings and most point towards trying a access a Null pointer - the textview is null

The `list_item_books.xml` xml file is a `MaterialCardView` with this TextView contained:

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Book Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgBook"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtBookName" />
```

The input for the program: is pulling data from an `ArrayList` which is coded in `AllBooksActivity.java` here:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_books2);

        adaptor = new BookRecViewAdaptor(this);
        booksRecView = findViewById(R.id.booksRecView);

        booksRecView.setAdapter(adaptor);
        booksRecView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book(1, "IQ84", "Haruki Murakami", 1350, "https://img1.od-cdn.com/ImageType-100/0111-1/%7B2B3729CD-27EC-42E1-BC51-298AAEE0AF7D%7DImg100.jpg",
        "A Work of maddening brilliance", "Long Description"));
        adaptor.setBooks(books);

    }
}
```

[2/1/2023 UPDATE] thank you for your comments/suggestions, I am finding it easier to post code in the original query format.

I am declaring `txtName` here:

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView parent;
        private ImageView imgBook;
        private TextView txtName;
        ...
```

I am initializing `txtName` here:

```
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
            imgBook = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBook);
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

        }
```

The `txtName` value is coming from the arrayList (`ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();`)
If I rem out this line of code:
`holder.txtName.setText(books.get(position).getName());`
No error is thrown however the value of `txtName` is not being set.

Comment: This means that `txtName` is not initialized in the ViewHolder

Comment: This is where I create my ViewHolder:
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_book, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }
...so *where* does txtName get initialized

Comment: Not in onCreateViewHolder, but in the `ViewHolder` class itself; in its constructor specifically

Comment: have you init your textview?

Comment: Thank you again Zain (and Urvish) - I've adjusted my main query to provide more information see above `[2/1/2023 UPDATE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a class the extends ViewHolder inside your adapter. that is where you initiate your Views.

a simple example

```
// this can reside inside your Adapter class
class VHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        
        // declare it
        TextView txtName;

        public vHolder(View item){
         // you initiate your views here.
         txtName = item.findViewById(R.id.txtBookName);

        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply TG - I've adjusted my main query to provide more information see above `[2/1/2023 UPDATE]`

Comment: @kiteandwindsurfer  you are welcome. from the code you provided,  you are initialising some thing else and not the one in the xml. that is if your code is the same with the one provided here. because in your xml you have a TextView with id  `txtBookName` and you are accesing it with different id  `txtName`   so `txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);` should be replaced by `txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBookName);`

Comment: YES - that was it!  Thanks so much @TG. Kahsay!!

Answer (score 1):

In your viewHolder, initialize textView as follow:

```
txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBookName);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sohaib - I've adjusted my main query to provide more information see above `[2/1/2023 UPDATE]`

Comment: You are using wrong ID.. use this `  android:id="@+id/txtBookName"` as per your question